# How to link to full size images from thumbnails? same directory, different file names

Tags: php

I have a /productname/images/ folder that includes both full size and thumbnails, but the filenames are different by one word (fullsize vs thumb).

```
$directory = "$company/$make/images/";
 $images = glob($directory_name."*_thumb*");
  foreach ($images as $image) {
   echo '<a href="'.$image.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'"></a>';
  }
```

So this is working great, but is linking the thumbs to themselves, obviously. How can I change the link to point to the full size version?

example filenames in /images/:

```
productname_1_thumb.jpg
productname_1_fullsize.jpg
productname_2_thumb.jpg
productname_2_fullsize.jpg
productname_3_thumb.jpg
productname_3_fullsize.jpg
etc etc
```

Should I just make a thumbs directory and separate them, make this a little simpler? Is that a more standard way of sorting thumbs vs full images? I don't mind doing that if it is standard practice to do it that way instead of lumping them all in the same dir like I am currently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use `str_replace`

```
$directory = "$company/$make/images/";
$images = glob($directory_name."*_thumb*");
foreach ($images as $image) {
   $fullsize = str_replace('thumb','fullsize',$image);
   echo '<a href="'.$fullsize.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'"></a>';
}
```

Comment: Waiting on the timer to run out to allow me to do so ;) "You can accept this answer in 2 minutes"

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `echo` line with:

```
echo '<a href="'.str_replace("_thumb", "_fullsize", $image).'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'"></a>';
```

This would be the easiest way, but the only constraint is that you can't have 2 occurrences of "_thumb" in the filename, or they'll both be replaced. If that's the case, you can use a simple regex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 2 occurrences thankfully shouldn't be a problem with my naming scheme (so far).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array that will have both Thumb and Main image on the same iteration.

**Example**:

```
$images = array(
 "productname_1_thumb.jpg" => "productname_1_fullsize.jpg",
 "productname_2_thumb.jpg" => "productname_2_fullsize.jpg",
);
```

After you have something like the above you could iterate through them like:

```
foreach($images as $key => $value){
 echo '<a href="'.$key .'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$value.'"></a>';
}
```

Even though i will agree that using str_replace to just change between _fullsize and _thumb should be the easiest you can go with.